# Compress a video for android using ffmpeg

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, video, telegram, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compress a video to send it around in a messenger. Normally I would use something like

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 output.mp4
```

but if I send it around in a messenger app like telegram afterwards, I can only watch it on my PC but not my smartphone (I tested different devices) although the codec is said to be supported: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

What is the best way to compress a video for messengers in mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

The solution may be just to **reconfigure (install) ffmpeg with x265 headers** by setting `--enable-libx265` for build as in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libx265)

However keep in mind that x265 encoding/decoding is still relatively new and is not implemented/present well enough in Android devices unless you have a newer/branded device*.
*(hw support, optimizations)*

**generally speaking. - even 2017's Galaxy S8 has built-in HEVC support even in official camera app*